# Cannot set resolution using camera.resolution of picamera

Tags: python, camera, raspberry-pi

I'm writing a python script that will have a ASCII menu to set up a timelapse. And send images to my web server or a usb if server is not avalable.

I'm doing threaded script. so im not sure if its a thread problem or what but I'm getting the error: `TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable`.

My code ([full code](http://ideone.com/ww8fvc)):

```
class timelaps(threading.Thread):
  """docstring for timelaps"""
  def __init__(self, res, delay, numberOfImages):
    super(timelaps, self).__init__()
    self.delay = delay
    if delay < 20:
      self.delay = 20
      pass
    self.numberOfImages = numberOfImages


  def run(self):
    currentImage = 0
    camera = picamera.PiCamera()
    camera.resolution(2592, 1944)
```

It's on the line `camera.resolution(2592, 1944)` that I'm getting the error. 
According to [Picamera Docs](http://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/release-1.9/quickstart.html) there should only be `camera.resolution(2592, 1944)` and the resolution should be set to that. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to those docs, `camera.resolution` is a simple attribute, not a method.

Instead of

```
camera.resolution(2592, 1944)
```

...you should be doing:

```
camera.resolution = (2592, 1944)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to assign `(2592, 1944)` to `camera.resolution`:

```
camera.resolution = (2592, 1944)
```